# Collecting packages and reexporting in scala

Tags: scala

I find myself replacing bash and python with a lot of things like

```
$ gunzip -c bigFile | scala -e "
import SimpleIO._
import java.util.HashSet
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val h = new HashSet[String]
ByLine(l => {h.add(l); true}) // ByLine applies lambda to each line on stdin 
h.asScala.foreach(x => println(x) })
" | ...
```

for reasons of expressiveness and performance.

While I can express a lot of logic in a readable way with a few lines of scala, it turns out I need a boatload of imports to make anything non trivial work. This is just noisy when reading scripts and distracts from logic. I would like to be able to import a lot of common packages into a single "namespace" / meta-package and them just have one single import for everything. Is there any way to do this in?

Note most jvm start up lag will get dwarfed by the scale of the computation so unnecessary imports are not that huge of a deal.